# Wildfly Swarm (Thorntail) cannot start - InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly, thorntail

I've got a problem with my JavaEE application, I tried to create app which will be automatically deployed, so I've chosen Thorntail but after launching it with `mvn thorntail:run`, I've got this error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:53)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.main(MainInvoker.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ArchiveImportException: Could not obtain ZIP File from File
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.initializeConfigView(Swarm.java:635)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.<init>(Swarm.java:254)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.<init>(Swarm.java:192)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.<init>(Swarm.java:179)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:739)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.importer.ArchiveImportException: Could not obtain ZIP File from File
        at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.zip.ZipImporterImpl.importFrom(ZipImporterImpl.java:178)
        at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.zip.ZipImporterImpl.importFrom(ZipImporterImpl.java:157)
        at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.zip.ZipImporterImpl.importFrom(ZipImporterImpl.java:49)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.initializeConfigFiltersClassPath(Swarm.java:693)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.initializeConfigFilters(Swarm.java:643)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.initializeConfigView(Swarm.java:632)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.impl.base.importer.zip.ZipImporterImpl.importFrom(ZipImporterImpl.java:176)
        ... 15 more
```

My pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.edu</groupId>
    <artifactId>money-transfer-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <javamoney.version>1.3</javamoney.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>
        <junit.version>5.1.0</junit.version>
        <junit.surefire.provider>1.3.0</junit.surefire.provider>
        <assertj.version>3.11.1</assertj.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.war.plugin.version>3.2.2</maven.war.plugin.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.22.0</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <version.thorntail>2.2.0.Final</version.thorntail>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
                <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
            <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
            <version>${javamoney.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>money-transfer-app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
                <artifactId>thorntail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the beginning, I thought it's caused by Java 10 version, but after downgrade to 8 problems still occurs. Thank you in advance for all your hints

Edit.
After `mvn clean package` and `java -jar target/money-transfer-app-thorntail.jar` there is another error

```
2018-09-10 19:37:05,388 ERROR [stderr] (main) org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: THORN0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.undefined"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"money-transfer-app.war#h2DataBase\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.undefined]","jboss.persistenceunit.\"money-transfer-app.war#h2DataBase\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.undefined]"]}
```

Comment: Try running "mvn clean package" first as it may need to download some JARs that aren't present locally yet

Comment: `mvn clean package` and `java -jar target/money-transfer-app-thorntail.jar` and the problem still occurs but there is another stack trace, I'll add it to the post above

Comment: Regarding your first errors, I'd recommend you to take a step back and start from a [simple working example](https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-examples). Regarding your second error, you're basically missing your H2 datasource. In order to configure it, you could use the Swarm's [How to create a datasource](https://howto.wildfly-swarm.io/create-a-datasource) and [Datasource User Guide](https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/common/datasources.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help, you're right, my problem was related to the wrong datasource configuration, now application works fine :)

Comment: @MateuszR awesome!! I'd now suggest you to place your fix as a response and mark it as _Answered_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `persistence.xml` file was a source of the problem, I've configured my H2 datasource and now application works fine

Previous version of `persistence.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="h2DataBase" transaction-type="JTA">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

After changes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
        <class>model.Account</class>
        <class>model.Owner</class>
        <class>model.payments.Payment</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

The persistence.xml was most likely not the cause of your problem.

If I understand Thorntail correctly, it is pulling dependencies from your maven repository expecting them to already be there. If they for some reason are not already there (for example, your pom is missing the dependencies that Thorntail needs), it will simply fail while reading the jar files. If that is the case, then maybe the error handling could be improved upon.